# cannot import name 'TrainingArguments' from 'transformers'

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I am trying to fine-tune a pretrained huggingface BERT model. I am importing the following

```
from transformers import (AutoTokenizer, AutoConfig,
                              AutoModelForSequenceClassification, TrainingArguments, Trainer)
```

and get the following error:

```
cannot import name 'TrainingArguments' from 'transformers'
```

Trainer also cannot import.

I currently have tensorflow 2.2.0, pytorch 1.7.1, and transformers 2.1.1 installed

Answer (score 0):

Find out the version of the transformers lib installed.

```
import transformers

print(transformers.__version__)
```

Somehow `pip install` doesn't install the latest version. I think we need to have v4.20.0 or greater.

you can try the following to install the latest version.

```
git clone https://github.com/huggingface/transformers.git
cd transformers
pip install -e .
```

https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/installation#editable-install